# SELECT com campo repetido

Tags: sql-server

Estou com problemas para executar uma consulta SQL.

A consulta é:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CHAVE_FATO,COD_FILIAL,COD_DOCTO,NUM_DOCTO,DATA,VALOR_TOTAL,VALOR_LIQUIDO,COD_CLI_FOR,NOME_CLI_FOR,COD_VEND_COMP,NOME_VEND_COMP,COD_PRODUTO,DESC_PRODUTO_EST,NOME_SECAO,QTDE_UND,QTDE_PRI,QTDE_AUX,VALOR_UNITARIO,VALOR_TOTAL_ITEM 
FROM [SATK].[dbo].entrada 
WHERE DATA > '2018-01-01 00:00:00' 
ORDER BY NUM_DOCTO ASC
```

Não funciona, o retorno continua mostrando valores repetidos na coluna NUM_DOCTO.

Preciso eliminar isso, mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Distinct faz a distinção de TUDO. E não apenas de uma coluna

Comment: Tem de agrupar colunas pela clausula GROUP BY as que podem ser assim agrupadas, outras você pode usar funções tipo MIN, MAX até chegar num resultado que lhe satisfaça. Porém todas as colunas tem de ser tratadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementando a resposta com `group by`, você precisa indicar em caso repetido, qual será o registro escolhido a ser exibido. Pode ser com MIN (menor), MAX (maior), SUM (soma), AVG (média), COUNT (quantidade).

Um exemplo seria:

```
SELECT MAX(CHAVE_FATO),MIN(COD_FILIAL),MAX(COD_DOCTO),NUM_DOCTO,MIN(DATA),MAX(VALOR_TOTAL),MAX(VALOR_LIQUIDO),MAX(COD_CLI_FOR),MAX(NOME_CLI_FOR),MAX(COD_VEND_COMP),MAX(NOME_VEND_COMP),MAX(COD_PRODUTO),MAX(DESC_PRODUTO_EST),MAX(NOME_SECAO),MAX(QTDE_UND),MAX(QTDE_PRI),MAX(QTDE_AUX),MAX(VALOR_UNITARIO),MAX(VALOR_TOTAL_ITEM) 
FROM [SATK].[dbo].entrada 
WHERE DATA > '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY NUM_DOCTO
ORDER BY NUM_DOCTO ASC
```

Mas fique atento, neste caso será exibido apenas uma linha. Caso tenha mais de um produto vinculado a este documento, virá no resultado apenas um respeitando a função de agregação (min, max, sum...).

Answer (score 0):

Use **GROUP BY**

```
SELECT DISTINCT CHAVE_FATO,COD_FILIAL,COD_DOCTO,NUM_DOCTO,DATA,VALOR_TOTAL,VALOR_LIQUIDO,COD_CLI_FOR,NOME_CLI_FOR,COD_VEND_COMP,NOME_VEND_COMP,COD_PRODUTO,DESC_PRODUTO_EST,NOME_SECAO,QTDE_UND,QTDE_PRI,QTDE_AUX,VALOR_UNITARIO,VALOR_TOTAL_ITEM 
FROM [SATK].[dbo].entrada 
WHERE DATA > '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY NUM_DOCTO
ORDER BY NUM_DOCTO ASC
```

Mais informações em: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Dá o seguinte erro: Mensagem 8120, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
Column 'SATK.dbo.entrada.CHAVE_FATO' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.